# Installed Ibus-avro, open-keyboard, ibus-daemon is running background but unable to type in Bengali in MX Linux KDE

Tags: kde, ibus, mx-linux

So for stability issues, I had to switch back to MX Linux, in its KDE version, since I am a KDE lover. But this time, something very unusual happened. I installed ibus-avro properly, added that in ibus-preferences, added the required lines in ~/.bashsrc and made ibus-daemon run automatically upon booting. Ibus-daemon is running in the background, I can select Avro phonetic, but whatever I type comes in plain English, not in Bengali. To mention, Bengali fonts are visible in chrome or any kind of docx format. But don't know why, ibus-daemon is having trouble typing Bengali, despite selecting Avro phonetic in the input method. Can anyone help me in this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was with KDE, it seems to have a hard time with IBus. IBus usually prefers gtk file finders, whereas, by default, in KDE, the file finder package is Qt. So it(IBus) gets itself stuck in a collision. And eventually, the problem has no apparent solution. Even you log out after installation, you may see that IBus is not working. Most of the time, after installing a new input method through IBus in KDE, you are advised to shut down to things take effect.